# Redefine \part style

Tags: sectioning, parts

I'm using `\documentclass{book}`. I want to modify my `\part` style so that I can get a page that for instance illustrates the following content (basically Part title + a quote at the bottom):

```
\begin{flushleft}
\chapter*{\Huge\scshape Part I:\\ Part Title}
\end{flushleft}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Part I: Part Title}


\vspace*{3cm}
\epigraph{``bla bla.''}{Mr. Bla-Bla}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option would be to use the [`epigraph`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epigraph) package for the epigraph and the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to easily customize the part heading format. A little example (notice that `\epigraphhead` has to be used *before* `\part`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\Huge\scshape\filright}
  {\partname~\thepart:}
  {20pt}
  {\thispagestyle{epigraph}}
\makeatother
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}


\begin{document}

\epigraphhead[450]{Fairy tales are more than true: not because they tell us that dragons exist, but because they tell us dragons can be beaten.\par\hfill\textsc{C.K. Chesterton}}
\part{A Test Part Title}

\end{document}
```

The resulting document:

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks! My problem is mainly the fact that I can not play around with the style of the text in the part heading. I like it for instance to be left aligned and \scshape. Is it possible to do it in your code? Basically I want these properties => \Huge\scshape

Comment: @LatexQuest I've updated my answer using now the `titlesec` package to achieve the desired formatting for the part headings; this formatting can also be achieved without `titlesec` but then the code will be longer. Is is something like that what you needed?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very nice. Can we modify it to be like: Part I: ... I want a ":" after part. My final goal is actually to design a heading style for it. For instance similar to the one in the picture above! Is it possible to have put the "A test part title" in the picture above and a quote below that like what you have given?

Comment: @LatexQuest please make up your mind. It would have been better to mention the desired style from the beginning to avoid wasting time and effort. Of course, that style can be produced, but where should now the colon ":" be? Why are you duplicating your questions? Either wait for Herbert to add the epigraph in the other question or add the epigraph yourself. I see no point in having two questions answered by two willing to help people but duplicating effort and wasting time. Do you really want me to keep working on this answer?

Comment: I modified my question. Can we have ":" as I explained?

Comment: @LatexQuest please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help. I tried your code. Standalone, Your MWC works perfectly. But, when I apply it to my document I have some problems which I'd like to modify. 1) In the TOC I see the title of the part, but in the corresponding page I do not see it! I just see Part I: ... empty space ... quote. 2) Can we modify what appears in the TOC? I like to see "Part I: A Test ... " with `\scshape` font there.

Comment: @LatexQuest Without code it's almost impossible to see what's causing the problem in 1). Please compose a minimal, complete document (like the one in my answer) illustrating the problem mentioned. For problem 2), since it's not directly related to the problem discussed here, please open a fresh new question; this is not a forum and we try to keep, idf possible, just one question per post.

Comment: But this is a related question! If I want to explain this in a new question, I have to explain things from scratch! You don't agree?!

Comment: @LatexQuest problem 1) is perfectly related, as I said, so please compose a MWE illustrating the problem and add it as an edit to your question. Problem 2) is related, but not directly, since it's about the ToC entry formatting and this has nothing to do with the heading formatting (which is the issue discussed here), so the best thing to do is to open a fresh new question.

Comment: I cannot easily find the source of problem one! My document is a very large one. I thought you might see that immediately ... or it might be a mistake in your code when applied to a more general framework. I'll do that for the second question, but like I said, I have to explain things from scratch.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina How can I prevent clearpage before and after part?

Comment: When I try this, it works well on the part page, but it also creates a copy of the epigraph on the last page of the chapter preceding the part page. Is there a known work-around?