# Epigraph on Part Page

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr, titlesec, parts, epigraphs

I used the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192851/redefine-part-style) to get a nice, customizable epigraph on a part page.

However, the solution uses the command `\usepagestyle{epigraph}`, and because of this, the part page has a pagenumber, which it normally doesn't have. I tried getting rid of the pagenumber by for example changing `\usepagestyle{epigraph}` to `\usepagestyle{empty}`, but then the complete epigraph disappears.

What I need to do then, is to redefine the epigraph pagestyle to be exctly the same, but without page numbers. How do I do this? (I can't seem to find the definition of the epigraph pagestyle in the `.sty` file)

I am using the `tufte-book` class, which should be identical to the standard book class for this discussion.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
%\documentclass{book}%same result
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\part}%
[display]%
{\filleft\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont\scshape}%
{\fontsize{90}{90}\selectfont\thepart}%
{20pt}%
{\thispagestyle{epigraph}}%
\makeatother
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}

\begin{document}
\epigraphhead[450]{In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice.\par\hfill\textsc{---Yogi Berra}}
\part{Test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `tufte-book` class is not the same as `book`; please, provide a MWE.

Comment: @egreg I included a MWE, the result of compiling with `\documentclass{book}` and `\documentclass{tufte-book}` is the same for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need epigraphs on part pages, this ought to work (patching the `epigraph` page style so its footer is empty):

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\filleft\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont\scshape}
  {\fontsize{90}{90}\selectfont\thepart}
  {20pt}
  {\thispagestyle{epigraph}}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\epigraphhead
 {\let\@evenfoot}
 {\let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\epigraphhead[450]{In theory, there is no difference between theory and 
practice.\par\hspace*{\fill}\textsc{---Yogi Berra}}

\part{Test}

\end{document}
```