# How to insert a regular epigraph in a part of a book?

Tags: sectioning, books, parts, epigraphs

The documentation of the [epigraph package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/epigraph) mentions that epigraphs on part pages are not supported and offers an alternative, but this does not allow to insert a regular epigraph with a quote and an author, only the quote part. How can I insert a regular epigraph, that looks like a chapter epigraph, in a part instead of a chapter? Note: I am completely open to using a different package if `epigraph` is not the best for the job. I checked the existing answers, but they are either about an epigraph without an author name, or about other document types (e.g. `memoir`, not `book`).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262892/161015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code from  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262892/161015

I found that a `\cleardoublepage` is needed before the epigraph of the part.

[image: z]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}  

\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dumy text

%%% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262892/161015
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\filleft\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont\scshape}
{\fontsize{90}{90}\selectfont\thepart}
{20pt}
{\thispagestyle{epigraph}}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\epigraphhead
{\let\@evenfoot}
{\let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot}
{}{}
\makeatother
% **********************************

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter*{Celestial navigation}
    \epigraphhead[70]{\epigraph{Star crossed lovers.}{\textit{The Bard}}}       
    
    \kant[1-5]  

    \section{General}
    \epigraph{Example is the school of mankind,and they will learn at no other.}%
{\textit{Letters on a Regicide Peace}\\ \textsc{Edmund Burke}}
    
    \kant[5]

    \cleardoublepage % needed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \epigraphhead[450]{Fairy tales are more than true: not because they tell us that dragons exist, but because they tell us dragons can be beaten.\par\rule[0.7ex]{\epigraphwidth}{.4pt} \par \hfill\textsc{C.K. Chesterton}}
    \part{Part title}
    \kant[8]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\part{title}` immediately ends with a `newpage`. The following MWE shows how to put an epigraph before and after a `\part` title.

```
% epipartprob.tex  SE 599262

\documentclass[a4paper]{book}  

\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@endpart}{} % don't force a \newpage after the part title
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Celestial navigation}
    \epigraph{Star crossed lovers.}{\textit{The Bard}}    
    
    \lipsum[1]

    \section{General}

    \epigraph{Example is the school of mankind,and they will learn at no other.}%
{\textit{Letters on a Regicide Peace}\\ \textsc{Edmund Burke}}
    
    \lipsum[2]

\section{Apart}
\epigraph{The whole is more than the sum of the parts}{\textit{Metaphysica}\\ Aristotle}

\lipsum[3]

%% put epigraphs before and after the part title

    \part{Part title}
\epigraph{The whole is more than the sum of the parts (I)}{\textit{Metaphysica}\\ Aristotle}

\epigraphhead[150]{\epigraph{The whole is more than the sum of the parts (II)}{\textit{Metaphysica}\\ Aristotle}}

\newpage % now go to the next page

    \lipsum[3]

\part{Second} 
% DON't FORGET THE \newpage
\newpage
\lipsum[4]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]