# Titlesec, equivalent for \chaptertitlename

Tags: titlesec

In `titlesec`, you have the command `\chaptertitlename` which is very useful if you want to customise you title with `\titleformat`:

> ```
> \usepackage{titlesec}
>
>
> \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
>     {\chaptertitlename \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
> ```

Now, if I want to do the same with the `\part` title what is the equivalent of `\chaptertitlename`? Is there a `\parttitlename` or a `\partname`?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192851/redefine-part-style) it could be helpful for you.

Comment: There is `\partname`; `titlesec` uses `\chaptertitlename` because its value can change between the main part and the appendix (and it's more convenient than `\@chapapp`).